# Choosing the right TCO fuse temp. for varistor

Tags: mov

What is the temperature value of a TCO (thermal cutoff fuse)
which should be chosen in order to protect a metal oxide varistor (MOV)?
(I mean cut the current to the varistor, before a catastrophic failure.)

Lets say for example: a 7D391(220vac)varistor.
what is the range of temperature (+/-) that a MOV
start to fail(burn)?
And do all MOV size (7D,10D,14D...) and all MOV rated voltage burn, more or less, at the same range of temperature?

Comment: the acceptable temperature range of any component will be given in its data sheet. But to be honest, you are trying to protect a thermal protection device with a thermal protection device: This **screams** [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), and I'll happily retract my "vote to close" the moment you explain (with a circuit schematic, if at all possible) why you'd want to do that.

Comment: Considering you have 23 questions, of which only 8 have positive votes: maybe it's generally worth adding more context to your questions.

Comment: I was trying to delete this question and ask a simple one,but i have noticed that you block me to ask new question.what a pity:( So my simple question is:what is the temperature(+/-)that the mov is starting to burn,while its operation surface tem. is 125°C?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with "blocking". Anyways, you can't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: Can you,at least,answer to my previous comment?what is the temperature(+/-)that the mov is starting to burn?It will be very helpful.

Comment: see my first comment: in the datasheet, it says that. I have no datasheet to your MOV, so I can't help you. Read your datasheet. full stop.

Comment: I was searching in several datasheet of several brands(before and again after i asked here my question)and no one mentioned the combustion temp.of the varistor.Only the operation temperature of the varistor,ambient temp.etc...I understand that you don't like to help,so,anyway,thanks for your time.

Comment: I try to help, and you'll find that my reputation count kind of reflects that. But you're very resitant to help. You've got a datasheet that specifies a maximum permissible operating tempererature, what else do you need? Why would you even care for combustion temperature unless you want to build a bomb?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help.Most of varistor data sheet says:125°C,but it says operation temperature,not max temperature.I would like to prevent the varistor from burning and not to cut the current just because the varistor's temperature is alittle above its temperature limits.So,it seems to be wrong to choose a 125°c TCO to cutoff the current(permanently)while the combustion temp.is far above.So,i try to figure out what TCO open temperature value should be chosen considering the combustion temperature?

Comment: No, you mustn't design for anything above its limits. These are limits. You do not go "slightly above". That's plain wrong.

Comment: Okay,but just for clarify.When the datasheet says:"mov operation temperature-125°C"Is this the limit that i should refer to?it doesn't say maximum allowed temperature or something like that.It just refer to the operating temperature or operating surface temperature.(but not max)

Comment: I don't have access to the datasheet, so I can't tell you. You'll typically find such numbers in tables *titled* "absolute maximum ratings".

Comment: Okay.I finally find your refering title on other datasheets.It appears that not all the datasheets are using this title,so i couldn't know before if the spec.was refer to the max temp.Now it is clear.Thanks for your guidance,even though i didn't get an answer to my opening question.Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there appears to be little guidance on what the appropriate temperature selection is - it will depend considerably on the thermal contact between the TCO and the MOV.  You can get MOVs with built-in TCOs - Littelfuse seem to choose 200C as their cut-off.  But that is probably not the correct answer for a TCO simply pressed against an MOV.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would just say that I know exactly why the OP is asking this question, and with a bit of Googling, it appears that putting a TCO in series with an MOV is a normal thing to do.  It's there to stop the MOV catching fire if it fails short circuit.  So the TCO should only operate if the MOV is outside its normal operating range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367463/maximum-fuse-rating-before-a-mov-varistor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really going to be possible to select the correct TCO operating temperature without knowing how the MOV and the TCO are connected together thermally.

It may come down to performing experiments and seeing what's the lowest rating TCO that won't fail in normal operation, but will fail when the MOV overheats.

Manufacturers such as Littelfuse now manufacture MOVs with a built-in TCO to eliminate this problem.  There may be one that suits your needs.

Comment: I was going to connect the MOV body to the TCO body,rather than connecting the built in TCO+MOV and you were right,it is for cutoff current to MOV before it catching fire.This was the reason whyi asked what is the temp. which the MOV start burning.So,if the maximum allowed operating temp.of the MOV is 125°C and the TCO takes time(few seconds)until it actually sense the heat and cut-off the current,what do you think should be the right cutoff temp. of the MOV?less than 125°C,equal to 125°C or maybe higher than that,since the combustion temp. of the MOV is ,anyway,much much higher than 125°C.

Comment: I would like to add that i understood that the TCO mustn't design above the MOV limits:125°C(as,MarcusMüller,mentioned),but wat the TCO temperature should be?equal to the max temp of the MOV(125°C)or less?

Comment: A starting point would be the maximum operating temperature of the MOV.  But as the manufacturers seem to offer no guidance, I wouldn't want to ship anything without actually testing it in a laboratory.  Taking the advice of some random person on the internet is not much of a safety case, for something that could potentially catch fire.

Comment: Yes,this is the problem,i don't find any guidance in TCO'S datasheet etc.My intention was to improve the circuit that has already fast fuse,but i guess that i will stay with the fast fuse protection and leave the TCO fuse for other tasks.Thanks.